# git commit filter

Tags: git, powershell

I am Running power shell script, get  last Pre-commit Id from Git Log,

> git log -1

But getting too much information

Comment: `grep`? I'm guessing power shell has that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Select-String`. To get full string try:

```
git log -1 --pretty=%B | Select-String -Pattern "Precommit-Verified"
```

To get only Precommit-Verified:

```
((git log -1 --pretty=%B | Select-String -Pattern "Precommit-Verified") -split ": ")[1]
```